# Как сделать библиотеки общими для всех папок в каталоге?

Tags: c

В каталоге имеется папка inc в ней общие библиотеки .h, также в каталоге имеется папки scr и com. В папках scr и com имеются файлы .c с зависимостями от файлов .h из inc. Как их связать между сабой?

Просто скопировать файлы из inc и закинуть их scr и com не вариант.

Comment: .h файлы подключаются через директиву #include. В MakeFile вы можете указать каталог для поиска этих .h-файлов

Comment: Подскажите, как?

Comment: Зависит от компилятора, в целом. Для GNU make параметр -I

Comment: к программе *make* вопрос вообще никак не относится. относится он к компилятору. который даже не озвучен.

Comment: Какой у вас компилятор или среда разработки?

Comment: Компилятор GNU, всё что нужно исправил используя параметр -I. Всем спасибо.